Why does my double-linked list display the numbers in reverse order, except for the first added number?
I wrote this code where you can add or remove numbers from a list, and then display the list. The problem is: it displays the numbers in reverse order, except for the first added number.
program obecny_seznam;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  ppolozka = ^tpolozka;
  tpolozka = record
               H: integer;
               prev,next: ppolozka;
            end;
var
  poc, pom, pom2, novy, akt: ppolozka;

//--------------------------------------------------------
procedure pridej; //add
begin
  if (poc = nil) and (akt = nil) then
    begin
      new(novy);
      readln(novy^.H);
      novy^.next := nil;
      novy^.prev := nil;
      poc := novy;
      akt := novy;
    end
  else if akt^.next = nil then
    begin
      new(novy);
      readln(novy^.H);
      novy^.prev := nil;
      novy^.next := nil;
      akt^.next := novy;
      novy^.prev := akt;
    end
  else
    begin
      pom := akt^.next;
      new(novy);
      readln(novy^.H);
      novy^.prev := nil;
      novy^.next := nil;
      pom^.prev :=  novy;
      novy^.next := pom;
      novy^.prev := akt;
      akt^.next := novy;
    end;
end;
//--------------------------------------------------------

//--------------------------------------------------------
procedure uber; //remove
begin
  if poc = nil then writeln('Seznam je prazdny.')
  else if akt^.next = nil then
    begin
      dispose(poc);
      akt := nil;
      poc := nil;
    end
  else if (akt^.prev = nil) then
    begin
      pom := akt;
      akt := akt^.next;
      akt^.prev := nil;
      dispose(pom);
      poc := akt;
    end
  else
    begin
      pom := akt^.prev;
      pom2 := akt^.next;
      pom^.next := pom2;
      pom2^.prev := pom;
      dispose(akt);
      akt := pom2;
    end;

end;
//--------------------------------------------------------

//--------------------------------------------------------
procedure zobraz; //display
begin
  pom := poc;
  if pom <> nil then
    begin
      while pom <> nil do
        begin
          if pom = akt then writeln('*', pom^.H)
                       else writeln(pom^.H);
          pom := pom^.next;
        end;
    end
                else writeln('Zasobnik je prazdny.'); 
end;
//--------------------------------------------------------

begin
  poc := nil;
  akt := nil;
  pridej;
  pridej;
  pridej;
  pridej;
  readln;
  zobraz;
  uber;
  readln;
  zobraz;
  readln;
end.

I don't know what else to change. If I add akt := novy at the end of procedure pridej (add) then procedure uber (remove) doesn't work anymore.

Remove akt from your logic and do everything without it. Linked lists is a basic concept of programming and you should have named (and tagged) it as such.

It would be easier to diagnose if you use local variables where possible.  For example, novy is only used within pridej, so make it local to that procedure.  pom is used in all three procedures, but independently in each, so should be local to each procedure. pom2 is unique to uber.

akt has to be there, it's a part of the assignement (which is voluntary and not marked fyi)

It would be better to use only english identifier names when you post here. Also, include comments about what you think your code is doing at various points. What is the purpose of pom and pom2?

Do everything without akt anyway - I'm sure it confuses you to understand your logic. Afterwards, if everything works as expected, you can incorporate your akt. Likewise your code is very redundant (new, readln and initializing .prev and .next could be done right away, because it happens in any case). @TomBrunberg Yes of course, double linked - how could I miss that?

IMHO, Stack Overflow is not a code review or debugging service. Why not ask your teacher?

Whenever playing with linked lists it is always a good idea to get out some paper and pencils and draw, step by step, how each and every operation works. Even after so many years I still do this whenever I dink with a linked list of any complexity beyond “push and item to the front” just to check that I am not messing something up.

Let's look at the most problematic pieces:

procedure pridej; //add
...
  else
    begin
      pom := akt^.next;


Whenever you read this portion keep in mind that akt still sticks with the 1st item in your list. This logic doesn't even work then adding a 3rd item anymore, because (akt=1st).next is always the 2nd item. Always.


...
      pom^.prev :=  novy;
      novy^.next := pom;


Now this doesn't make sense: some item's previous (left) member should be the new item? No wonder that you sort everything in front of the existing items. Likewise the new item's next (right) member shouldn't need to be assigned if it is supposed to be the last item.


      novy^.prev := akt;
      akt^.next := novy;
    end;
end;


This is wrong, as it voids the sense of having akt at all: either you leave it untouched, or you move it along with any item addition. That's why I wrote "try it first without any akt at all".

Where's the fundamental flaw? You nowhere store the last item of your list, only its first item. If you would also store the last one, you could easily add a new item after that and assign that new item as the last one. Such a variable is missing at all.
You can work without such a variable, but then you have to go from your first list item over .next in a loop until .next = nil to find the last item of your list. Have a read on the Wikipedia article on doubly linked lists which also mentions this concept.
